# How to sort qVector of Points3D only from one of its components. For example z

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I see this other post about sort qvector: [post_sort_qvector_simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391115/how-to-use-stl-algorithms-in-qt/28391188#28391188)

But I need some method to sort elements of my QVector.

I have something like this:

```
CartesianPoint point
std::vector<CartesianPoint> vector_points;
```

Where CartesianPoint is:

```
class CartesianPoint
{

public:

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

}
```

Then I need to sort vector_points only for z element of Cartesian point.

I know this is not possible but I need something like this

```
std::vector(vector_points.z.begin(), vector_points.z.end());
```

How I would solve this?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see this post. Could you type link here??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: `std::sort(std::begin(vector_points), std::end(vector_points), [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return (a.z < b.z); });` this sorts from least to greatest `z` value. See it [run here](http://ideone.com/ABKXTG).

Comment: Thanks it works fine. What I would do with this post?

Comment: Hi, I have a this problem.                                                                                                     I have a vector like this:  [vector_points_original](https://github.com/ivanoterouvigo/gbxml/blob/master/imgs/vector_points_001.png)