# Sort vectors by more conditions than one

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qvector

I asked in other post about: [my_old_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837293/how-to-sort-qvector-of-points3d-only-from-one-of-its-components-for-example-z)

But now I need more complex condition to sort my vector.

> **I have a vector like this:**  [vector_points_original](https://github.com/ivanoterouvigo/gbxml/blob/master/imgs/vector_points_001.png).   Then if I sort it for z of each point I have other vector like: [vector_points_sorted_by_Z](https://github.com/ivanoterouvigo/gbxml/blob/master/imgs/vector_points_002.png).    **But I need** vector_sorted_by_z and after sort first four points and second four points by y component. Could you help me?

Comment: Please post the text here instead of posting a link to an image of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<CartesianPoint>v{...};//place your values here      
//First, sort by Z    
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2){return p1.z < p2.z;});
//Define a compare-by-y lambda
auto yComp = [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2){return p1.y < p2.y;};
//Use yComp for first 4 v[]
std::sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4, yComp);
//And for the second
std::sort(v.begin() + 4, v.begin() + 8, yComp);
```

If you need to save `z` order while reordering by `y`, then `yComp = [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {return p1.y < p2.y && p1.z <= p2.z;};`

Answer (score 0):

Is it performance critical ? If not, just split your existing vector into two, sort by Y and then put the results back into a single vector ?

```
std::vector<Point3d> sortedByZ;
std::vector<Point3d> firstFour(sortedByZ.begin(), sortedByZ.begin() + 4);
std::vector<Point3d> lastFour(sortedByZ.begin() + 5, sortedByZ.end());

// Sort firstFour and lastFour independently

sortedByZ = firstFour;
sortedbyZ.insert(sortedByZ.end(), lastFour.begin(), lastFour.end());
```

?